# Creating non-odr-used literal type

Tags: c++, c++14

Please consider the following type definition:

```
struct lit
{
    enum { A, B } value;
    constexpr lit() : value(A) { }
    constexpr lit(int) : value(B) { }
};
```

According to the C++14 standard (3.9/10), this type qualifies as a literal type. Next, please consider the following usage scenario:

```
struct foo
{
    static constexpr lit a { };
    static constexpr lit b { 10 };
    static constexpr int i { 42 };
};

int main()
{
    lit a = foo::a;
    lit b = foo::b;
    int i = foo::i;

    std::cout << "a=" << a.value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "b=" << b.value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "i=" << i       << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Section 9.4.2/3 of the standard, while not stating it directly, implies that I don't have to specify definition for `static constexpr` members, *unless* they are odr-used (eg, consider `foo::i`).

When I compile the above with clang, it complains that I am missing definitions for `foo::a` and `foo::b` as it thinks they are odr-used. See example on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/49e52050ebfc569b).

gcc on the other hand swallows it just fine and happily prints out the correct result. Again, here is example on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d0afedb6f90cc3a).

So, my question is two-fold:

1. Are `foo::a` and `foo::b` really odr-used? And if so, please explain why and how they are different from `foo::i`.
2. What changes need to be done to `lit` to make it not require out-of-class definitions for `foo::a` and `foo::b`? In other words, I want `foo::a` and `foo::b` to behave the same way as `foo::i`.

UPDATE:

It seems Barry's answer is correct in terms of `lit` being odr-used. To illustrate, if I add the following function:

```
void bar(const int& x)
{
    std::cout << "bar(" << x << ")" << std::endl;
}
```

and the following line to main:

```
bar(foo::i);
```

gcc now complains as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Are `foo::a` and `foo::b` really odr-used?

I believe the answer is yes. We're copy constructing `a` and `b`. `lit` has an implicit copy constructor which is:

```
constexpr lit(lit const& rhs) = default;
```

That is, we're binding `foo::a` and `foo::b` to a reference, which makes them odr-used. This isn't a problem for `foo::i`, since `int` isn't a class type and thus does not have a copy constructor.

I'm not sure what you can do to avoid this, outside of just not copying the two literals and instead copying the enums (i.e. `auto a = foo::a.value;` does not odr-use `foo::a`).

Comment: But I think this falls under an exception in [basic.def.odr]/3 because `lit` has a *trivial* copy constructor which is used to perform the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion.

Comment: @Barry, thank you for your answer, but what about 3.2/3... oh yeah, that's what Brian is saying above

Comment: @Brian It's a very awkwardly worded sentence. It says that it's the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that doesn't invoke any non-trivial functions? But regardless, where are we converting to rvalue?

Comment: @Brian (btw, not saying you're wrong - I'm not sure one way or the other)

Comment: I am scratching my head around this sentence of [basic.def.odr]/3: A variable x whose name appears as a potentially-evaluated expression ex is odr-used by ex unless applying the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) to x yields a constant expression (5.20) that does not invoke any non-
trivial functions and, if x is an object, _ex is an element of the set of potential results of an expression e, where either the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion (4.1) is applied to e, or e is a discarded-value expression (Clause 5)._ Specifically, the italicized part

Comment: I think lvalue-to-rvalue conversion happens when the value stored in an lvalue is required, such as when it's copied. This is the case for arithmetic and pointer types, anyway. But I think the standard is rather ambiguous on whether it also applies to literal and POD classes.